# Не получается вывести span-элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ничего не появляется.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  $("#spanBox").append("<span>" + "</span>");
}
```

```css
span {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spanBox">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: не подключен JQuery

Answer (score 1):

для  свойство display: inline; по умолчанию.
А сейчас у вас в примере не подключен JQuery

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   $("#spanBox").append("<span>");
}
```

```css
span {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   background: #333;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spanBox"><span></span></div>
```

Comment: А теперь внимание! Интересный вопрос! Почему у вас в снипете белая полоса и как это исправить?)

Comment: Попробуйте теперь

Comment: Хитро) Но мне кажется, было бы лучше, если бы вы оставили пустое место и объяснили бы, откуда оно берется. Мне кажется, это будет полезнее!

Comment: Просто был непечатаемый символ типа пробела. Если код написать вот так, то проблема исчезает. <div id="spanBox"><span></span></div>

Comment: Я это знаю) Я хочу, что бы вы это добавили в ответ. И оставили оригинальную разметку автора со спаном внутри. Потому что у него вполне может возникнуть следующий вопрос - что за белая полоса и как ее убрать? Ну и показать решение сразу для автора.